# Is this code for Gaussian Mixture Model correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, expectation-maximization

I am learning GMM to do color segmentation. I found a good resource online with the following GMM code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
np.random.seed(0)

X = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=20)
X0 = X * np.random.rand(len(X)) + 15  # Create data cluster 1
X1 = X * np.random.rand(len(X)) - 15  # Create data cluster 2
X2 = X * np.random.rand(len(X))  # Create data cluster 3
X_tot = np.stack((X0, X1, X2)).flatten()  # Combine the clusters to get the random datapoints from above

class GM1D:

    def __init__(self, X, iterations):
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.X = X
        self.mu = None
        self.pi = None
        self.var = None

    def run(self):

        self.mu = [-8, 8, 5]
        self.pi = [1 / 3, 1 / 3, 1 / 3]
        self.var = [5, 3, 1]

        for iter in range(self.iterations):

            r = np.zeros((len(X_tot), 3))

            for c, g, p in zip(range(3), [norm(loc=self.mu[0], scale=self.var[0]),
                                          norm(loc=self.mu[1], scale=self.var[1]),
                                          norm(loc=self.mu[2], scale=self.var[2])], self.pi):
                r[:, c] = p * g.pdf(X_tot)  # Write the probability that x belongs to gaussian c in column c.
            for i in range(len(r)):
                r[i] = r[i] / (np.sum(self.pi) * np.sum(r, axis=1)[i])

            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
            ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

            for i in range(len(r)):
                ax0.scatter(self.X[i], 0, c=np.array([r[i][0], r[i][1], r[i][2]]), s=100)

            for g, c in zip([norm(loc=self.mu[0], scale=self.var[0]).pdf(np.linspace(-20, 20, num=60)),
                             norm(loc=self.mu[1], scale=self.var[1]).pdf(np.linspace(-20, 20, num=60)),
                             norm(loc=self.mu[2], scale=self.var[2]).pdf(np.linspace(-20, 20, num=60))], ['r', 'g', 'b']):
                ax0.plot(np.linspace(-20, 20, num=60), g, c=c)

            m_c = []
            for c in range(len(r[0])):
                m = np.sum(r[:, c])
                m_c.append(m)  # For each cluster c, calculate the m_c and add it to the list m_c

            for k in range(len(m_c)):
                self.pi[k] = (m_c[k] / np.sum(m_c))  # For each cluster c, calculate the fraction of points pi_c which belongs to cluster c

            self.mu = np.sum(self.X.reshape(len(self.X), 1) * r, axis=0) / m_c
            var_c = []

            for c in range(len(r[0])):
                var_c.append((1 / m_c[c]) * np.dot(((np.array(r[:, c]).reshape(60, 1)) * (self.X.reshape(len(self.X), 1) - self.mu[c])).T, (self.X.reshape(len(self.X), 1) - self.mu[c])))

            plt.show()
GM1D = GM1D(X_tot, 10)
GM1D.run()
```

Now my understanding is that in the Maximation step of EM, we must update the gaussian parameters (covariance matrix, mean and size of the gaussian(pi_c) ) In the code given above, I can see the values of pi_c and mean(mu) being updated but I don't think the value of the covariance matrix is updated. However, when I run the code it seems to be working (?). Can someone please help me determine if the code is correct or not. The code is from the following [resource](https://www.python-course.eu/expectation_maximization_and_gaussian_mixture_models.php)

Comment: Please read [Is it allowed to ask if my code is correct in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298303/is-it-allowed-to-ask-if-my-code-is-correct-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: It does look correct though.

Comment: @gnahum it does but I can't see the covariance matrix/std dev being updated after each iteration

Comment: The var is updating. The mean isn't however.

Comment: When I print statements for self.mu, the value does change, however var does not (according to me). Could you please show me where var is updating?